# Align columns horizontally (multicols)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol, multicolumn, nomenclature, nomencl

I have encounter an issue with multicols. I'm writing a document and I am using the class Thesis.cls from [here](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/thesis/thesis.cls).

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[noprefix,norefeq]{nomencl} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\item[\bfseries
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{Acronyms}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{Subscripts}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{N}}{Notation}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{Greek Letters}{}}}}%
]}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}    

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}    
\printnomenclature    
\end{multicols}

\nomenclature[N]{A}{Somthing}
\nomenclature[N]{A}{Somthing}
\nomenclature[N]{A}{Somthing}
\nomenclature[N]{A}{Somthing}
\end{document}
```

But I have a problem. The columns are not printed aligned (see figure below). I have an extra space before the "Subscript".

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is. In any case, it is really difficult to help you without more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open and close the `multicols` environment inside the `thenomenclature` environment, which can be done with the `\nompreamble` and `\nompostamble` hooks.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[noprefix,norefeq]{nomencl} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\item[\bfseries
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{Acronyms}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{Subscripts}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{N}}{Notation}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{Greek Letters}{}}}}%
]}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

Some text

\printnomenclature    

% populate the nomenclature with dummy entries    
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<60
\advance\count255 1
\edef\temp{\noexpand\nomenclature[N]{A}{\romannumeral\count255}}\temp
\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]